# closed loop operator for neural networks, final form.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, neural-networks

I'm reading the book about neural networks from Simon Haykin.
In the first section of recurrent neural networks plot this figure:
[image]

and he says that the system is linear.
So he discribes the system in the following manner:
$$y_k(n) = A[x'_j]   (I)$$

And
$$x'_j = x_j(n) + B[y_k(n)] (II)$$

He tells that $A$ and $B$ are "operators", and then he gets the closed-loop operator:
$$y_k(n) = \dfrac{A}{1-AB}[x_j(n)]$$
which is a operator too.

My question is, it looks like he just substituted $x'_j$ from $(II)$ into $(I)$ to get this result. But, since they are operators, a number-like algebra shouldn't be allowed. Am i missing some concept of operator?

Comment: This is an example of the awkward notation used in most deep learning papers. Depending on what the author means $1-AB$ could be a scalar or the inverse of $I-AB$ where $I$ is the identity 'operator'. I would not think about this too hard if I were you.